# Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference 'int com.android.server.job.controllers.JobStatus.getUid()'

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-jobscheduler

I'm getting an error

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference 'int com.android.server.job.controllers.JobStatus.getUid()'
```

there is a similar question
[android-job-issues](https://github.com/evernote/android-job/issues/92)

but I don't know what to do.

this is not simple nullpointerexception,see this：
[click this picture,you can see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZYlx.png)

my question is how to provent this.

this is my error log.

```
#1 main
java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int    com.android.server.job.controllers.JobStatus.getUid()' on a null object reference
1 android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1580)
2 android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1527)
3 android.app.job.IJobCallback$Stub$Proxy.jobFinished(IJobCallback.java:167)
4 android.app.job.JobService$JobHandler.handleMessage(JobService.java:147)
5 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
6 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
7 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5413)
8 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
9 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1037)
11 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

Comment: please add you full question with the error from logcat.

Comment: For those, who also get this issue: links: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=104302 , 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=170814

Comment: @AntonShkurenko but there is no answer. I also find this.  [https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/1622](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/1622)

Comment: Why this question is marked as duplicate? @Charu . Because the solution for null pointer can not solve the above issue.

Comment: why this marked as duplicate? This is android problem..